# Executing xpath in android

Tags: android, xml, xpath

I want to parse an XML file (execute XPATH)

I used SAX and not JDOM

How can i give item from query

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a small example in the [javax.xml.xpath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) package description:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/widgets/widget";
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("widgets.xml");
NodeSet nodes =
    (NodeSet) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

If you already have a `NodeList` then I think you can use a [different evaluate method](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20javax.xml.namespace.QName%29) instead.